# STRG-Key is pressed all the time

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I need to spam the left STRG-Key a few times to get it to work normally again. This is happening since a little water spill. Everything else works perfectly fine exept this one Key?
Is there a fix to that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Take it to a repair shop or buy a new keyboard.